# I can't install openJDK 7 in ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit)

Tags: java, dependencies, eclipse, openjdk, jdk

Using Ubuntu Software Center I tried to install OpenJDK 7 but got the following notification.

```
**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.


Details:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

openjdk-7-jre: Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.10.1) but 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.10.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
               Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:2.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
               Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
```

What is this problem about and how can I overcome it to install JDK? I just want to run eclipse on my machine. Which JDK and IDE should be better for ubuntu 12.10?? FYI, I'm new in Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 has reached its End of Life. It is better to upgrade to 14.04 or 14.10 instead.

Try the following commands

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Otherwise, install Oracle Java using this PPA

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

Comment: Oracle Java is proprietary,  right?  So he may want to check that option in the software settings ( under system settings )

Comment: Since the package is from a PPA, there is no need for it.

Comment: I just changed my software source from USC from 'select best server' and execute the following commands in terminal.


sudo apt-get clean &&
sudo apt-get autoclean &&
sudo apt-get autoremove &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade

It's working now!!